# excle vba loop limits

Tags: excel, vba

I have one loop 2 to ~28000 and innner loop with about 100 000 iterations. As I understand, there ir is some limit of iterrations, because I get overflow error.

If it helps, there is code

```
Sub slp()

Dim sx As Long
Dim sy As Long
Dim sr As Long
Dim att As Long

'SLP rindu skaits 23845
For sr = 2 To 23845
lapa = Sheets("SLP").Cells(sr, 5).Value
sx = Sheets("SLP").Cells(sr, 6).Value
sy = Sheets("SLP").Cells(sr, 7).Value
'sub metr
Dim attn As Long
Dim x1 As Long
Dim x2 As Long
Dim y1 As Long
Dim y2 As Long
Dim s1 As Long
Dim s2 As Long
Dim a12 As Long
Dim c1 As Long
Dim c2 As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim attn1 As Long
Dim slin As Long
Dim rindas As Long
attn = 1000000000
'liniju rindas
rindas = Sheets(lapa).Cells(Sheets(lapa).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For lr = 2 To rindas
'rindas ~100 000
'koordinasu kolonnas
x1 = Sheets(lapa).Cells(lr, 3).Value
y1 = Sheets(lapa).Cells(lr, 4).Value
x2 = Sheets(lapa).Cells(lr, 5).Value
y2 = Sheets(lapa).Cells(lr, 6).Value
slin = Abs((y2 - y1) * (sx - x1) - (x2 - x1) * (sy - y1))
s1 = Sqr((x1 - sx) ^ 2 + (y1 - sy) ^ 2)
s2 = Sqr((x2 - sx) ^ 2 + (y2 - sy) ^ 2)
a12 = Sqr((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)
c1 = (a12 ^ 2 + s2 ^ 2 - s1 ^ 2) / (2 * a12 * s2)
c2 = (a12 ^ 2 + s1 ^ 2 - s2 ^ 2) / (2 * a12 * s1)
'ja abu < cos pozitivi, tad punkts ir kaut kur blakus linijai nevis tuvāk kadam tas galapunktam
attn1 = WorksheetFunction.Min(s1, s2)
If c1 >= 0 And c2 >= 0 Then attn1 = slin
'meklejam mazako attalumu lidz visam linijam
att = WorksheetFunction.Min(attn, attn1)
attn = att
Next lr


Sheets("SLP").Cells(sr, 11) = att
Next sr
End Sub
```

at the beginning, I was just summing some values, there vas no if inside loop, and then it worked. Maybe somebody could suggest some optimisation of this code. Maybe I'm doing something not correct because I have very short experinece in Excel VBA.

Thank You!

Comment: At which line does it give the error? Overflow errors happen a lot when you assign a to large value to an integer variable, but it looks like you got that covered by declaring all your variables as long.

Comment: Variables that contain floating point numbers should be **DIM**'ed as Double rather than Long.

Comment: Not an answer, but may be related: while 0/0 produces a "division by 0" error, `(0*0)/0` produces an overflow error.  I suspect something similar is happening here.

Comment: Long variables can store numbers ranging from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. If you're outside that range, then you'll get an overflow. But I agree with @Gary'sStudent that it looks like you need the Double data type, not Long; it doesn't look like you're dealing with integers only.

Comment: I tried before all as double, it doesent worked. Now I put for all values exact type and excel is doing somethinig, no error.

Comment: Process stoped at row (sr=) 7956 with error:overflow. At that moment variable lapa is changing. When I try to set f.i. `for sr=7957 to 8000` I got automatically overflow.